# SAML SignIn Protocol and form-based authentication

Tags: saml-2.0

i need to integrate with SAP, they send the following URL with username and password authentication.
when i access this url i redirected to 
https://sts.xxxx/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=fVFbS8MwFP4rJe9t07oLDWuhrCgFlWFFwRfJmlMXSJOak8757007lPmgcB4OH%2Be7JRvkvRpYObqDfoD3EdAFdZWThtIlXa4yCGm23ocJiGW4hzYL04WgHazTlIqEBE9gURqdkzSiJKgRR6g1Oq6dh2iyCunCzyPN2FXGFvSFBJV3kJq7mXVwbkAWx%2Bgw8kF49GaOfom56DBWGJPg2tgW5nQ56bhCmFx2HFEe4QcpEcFOilujcezBNmCPsvVRBJxy4pOdeqWRzV1zMlrNDEeJTPMekLmWNeXdLfMd2GCNM61RpNhM12yuZC%2F4%2F9P5dxJSNOXu9ea52sQXOmfRgd17Yl3tjJLt51Sx5%2B5v3SRKZkSKsJtP2ahxgFZ2EoQvr5T52Frgzj%2BIsyOQuDib%2Fv7W4gs%3D&RelayState=oucqqvqvwzeoqzxboredvobeczosudqfexssqdr&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F

which requires login authentication as attached 1,,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksupP.png)

Questions: How can i access this service in .NET Programming?

Comment: What service? You have a link to ADFS for authentication, nothing else. It's true that SAP may redirect you to ADFS for authentication if you need to, but from a .NET perspective it's unclear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADFS security token service (STS) can be access pro grammatically. Here is an example that uses powershell https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/10/17/request-adfs-security-token-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow SAML2 protocol with SAMLRequest and SAMLResponse tokens.

Here is the [nice explanation](https://blog.surf.nl/en/saml-for-dummies/):

> SAML (or more specifically, SAML version 2.0) is what brings
>   Single-Signon to SURFconext – being able to authenticate only once to
>   your home university (or Identity Provider in SAML parlance) and
>   subsequently login to many applications (or Service Providers) without
>   having to type in a password again.

let’s take a look at what happens when someone wants to log in at a Service Provider (SP) that uses federated authentication for one of its customers (the IDP). For the sake of example, let’s say the SP is Google Apps and the IDP is an organisation called My University, where Alice is a student. The flow of SAML protocol messages can be illustrated in a diagram as follows:

[image]

Comment: thank you for reply, actually i understand the concept,i can access it from browser, what i need is 
how to consume this service in .NET Programtically

Comment: I'd imagine Microsoft came up with some library classes to support .NET apps. If not, you can go on http request/response level and consume SAMLRequest and SAMLResponse tokens.

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually this is POC only, my plan is to consume it in SharePoint WebPart or through BCS, any idea?